# Change ion-segment text color

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have below code and I want to change text color of the segment buttons

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-toolbar color="header">
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="tripType">
      <ion-segment-button value="OW">
        One Way
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="RT">
        Round Trip
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-content>
```

I can see $segment-button-ios-text-color as Saas variable but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: You want to change `One Way` this text color?

Comment: I want to change color of both buttons

Comment: Show me the styles you did to change the color of text?

Comment: I did not use any style, it is by default

Comment: then have a common class to `ion-segment-button` tags and change color

Comment: Kindly can you show me how ?

Comment: Do you have any `.css` file to change styles?

Comment: No I don't have .css file

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Basically we write styles in `css/scss` files and include them in html files.

You can write like this `<ion-segment-button value="OW" style="color: red;">` but that is not a good practice. Because if we write inline styles as I said, we can't override(can't be changed) them.

So, better to have a `css/scss` file and have a class to `<ion-segment-button>` like this `<ion-segment-button class="segment-button">` and write style in `css/scss` file as shown below and include it in html file

```
.segment-button {
    color: red; // here, instead of "red" you can use sass variable if it was already defined
}
```

The below code works same as above

```
$segment-button-ios-text-color: red
.segment-button {
    color: $segment-button-ios-text-color;
}
```

Comment: can we do same with scss

Answer (score 0):

You can override `$segment-button-ios-text-color` in **variables.scss** and it will be set for all segment buttons in the app for IOS App.

If you want to override for Android, set the value for  `$segment-button-md-text-color`

```
$segment-button-ios-text-color: red;
```

This will be set automatically in the build process by Ionic

If you want to override for one particular html,
set it within the corresponding scss file.
example for `home.html` with selector `home`, set the below in **home.scss**:

```
home{
 .segment-button {
    color: red; //as suggested by @Mr_Perfect
  }
}
```

Comment: you mean the scss variable?

Comment: how are you getting it? default color?

Comment: I created side menu project. Then created created one folder with in src/pages with with three files inside xxx.html, xxx.scss and xxx.ts. I have put my question code in .html file and putting your code inside .scss file

Comment: where did you set the scss variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146405/discussion-between-milind-and-suraj).

Comment: I am setting in page-list{ variable} in my xxx.scss file. page-list is my selector

Comment: no.. you need to set in variables.scss.. it is in theme folder..https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/

Comment: I forget to mention that I did it in variables.scss but still did not works

Comment: add the corresponding scss and also variable.scss to the question

Comment: this is my whole project https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9uaB7knZvBJX3ZJTUg0cWl0RG8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

remove color from:

```
<ion-toolbar color="header"> </ion-toolbar>
```

it overwrites the $segment-button-ios-text-color variable

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="tripType">
      <ion-segment-button value="OW">
        One Way
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="RT">
        Round Trip
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-content>
```

then you can now set the value in your app.scss or variables.scss

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in following ways:

- First, In  scss file write your color:

  ```
   .segment { color: red;}
  ```
- Then, In  html file do as follow:

  ```
  <ion-segment value="Providers">
    <ion-segment-button value="Providers" class="segment">
      <ion-label>Providers</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="Services" class="segment">
      <ion-label>Services</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
  ```